# Is there a similar module like Sequelize in Blazor webAssembly?

Tags: blazor, .net-5

In nodejs, When I make connection with RDB, I use sequelize.
It's good for changing DB whenever I want.
Also I can use raw queries with this.

I'm really new to .net 5 and trying to learn blazor webassembly,
and having trouble in making connection with RDB like mysql, mariadb, postgresql.
Is there a module that can do same thing as nodejs's sequelize?

Also, is SQL server completly free as postgresql?

Comment: You don't make a sql connection with web assembly. It runs on the client, in the browser. You call a back end piece to use DBs, generally an API. Web assembly is an alternative to frameworks like Angular or Vue, not to server side ones like Node. Use Blazor server-side for that, or better yet, create an API to properly separate concerns.

Comment: thx for cleaing my misunderstanding :)